# Differentiate between humans and robots using their mouse movement patterns

Tags: hci

I am looking for references that talk about the existence of a general pattern in mouse tracking data of humans when they do a matching game. I am going to use this knowledge to differentiate between humans and the robots trying to play the game as humans.
Does anybody know a reference about the mouse movement pattern of humans?
I would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Not the same thing that you ask for, but perhaps this can help you (see also the large reference section): [An Efficient User Verification System via Mouse
Movements](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~hnw/paper/ccs11.pdf)